# Why is member undefined?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, undefined, member, prototypal-inheritance

Why is the call to `alert()` popping up `undefined`? I'm guessing that Javascript's not using the `this` that I think it is. How can I fix the code while still making it read somewhat like non-prototypal inheritance code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Help</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var Foo = function (myName) {
                this.myName = myName;
            }

            Foo.prototype.sayName = function () {
                alert(this.myName);

            }

            var foo = new Foo("I am foo");

            var bar = {
                ask: function (fn) {
                    fn();
                }
            };

            function doIntroductions() {
                bar.ask(foo.sayName);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="doIntroductions();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` depends on **how** you call the function. You are calling the function in the context of the global object, where no property `sayName` exists. You need to set the context explicitly:

```
bar.ask(foo.sayName.bind(foo));
```

`bind` makes sure that `this` inside of `sayName` is `foo` when you call `fn`.